# Wierd pointer construct

Tags: c++, arduino

I've run across this pointer construction and I'm not familiar with it.
Can someone explain please.

```
void Test_GPS::begin(uint16_t baud)
{
    gpspointer->begin(baud);
}
```

What does the `->` do? And it seems recursive.

Comment: What is the type of `gpspointer`? This isn't quite recursive. Recursive would be `this->begin(baud)`. This is just calling the `begin` method on some other pointer for whatever reason.

Comment: Barring operator overloading, `a->b` is a shortand for `(*a).b`.

Comment: "1'm", are you serious?

Comment: It's described in any elementary introduction to pointers in both C and C++, so "wierd" is an exaggeration.

Comment: This question would be best answered by reading a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 2):

You should really get a C/C++ Book and learn your language, before you start programming.

`->` is the dereferencing operator for Pointers. When you have a pointer `gpspointer` the expression `(*gpspointer)` returns the object `gpspointer` points to. `(*gpspointer).begin(baud)` is the same as `gpspointer->begin(baud)`. It just increases readability.

Your code will recurse only if `gpspointer=this`.

Comment: Thank-you ikrabbe.  Makes sense now.  I hadn't seen that representation before.  My K&R book doesn't mention it.

Comment: K&R is about ANSI C, not C++ and I doubt that K&R does not mention the `->` operator. Hmm It's about 25 years ago I read my K&R, so maybe I'm wrong on this.

Comment: @Trillian86 The index says it's on pages 131 and 201 in the 2nd edition.